# How to remove Down icon from select in firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

Helolo Every oie,

anyone have idea to how to remove right corner icon from select in full screen firefox.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai seems like none of the solution in your link works nowdays :)

Answer (score 0):

I have answered to such question here before.

The idea is to use a mask. http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nKuhs

You can even serve this CSS to only FF: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/retfC

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  div {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px outset;
    overflow:hidden;/*where no pseudo is used;*/
  }
  div.pseudo:before {
    content:'';
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    width:1.2em;
    margin-left:-1.1em;
    height:1.3em;
    background:white;
    position:relative;
    /* you may add
      padding:inherit;
      line-height:inherit;
      background:inherit;
      ...
      */
  }
  select {
    border:none;
    margin-left:-1px;
  }
}
```

Comment: the -moz-appearence:none; works no more , at least in MSW OS